# How can I select all the elements of a listbox by marking a checkbox?

Tags: asp.net, .net, checkbox, listbox

I have a checkbox, I want that when it is checked selected all the elements of a list (which its elements are loaded dynamically) and when unchecking it all are deselected. I know that I have to program inside the checkedchanged event but I can't find the property or method to select all the elements of the list. I am working on asp.net, however I must not use javascript.

```
        private void chkTodos_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

              for (int i = 0; i < milista.Item.Count; i++)
              {---------------------------}

              if (!chkTodo.Checked)
              {
                ----
              }
        }
```

Note: The version of .net I work with is very old. So some properties of the listbox like setSelected don't work.

Comment: how do you show the data on page? It's either you have code in html/js to iterate the collection and display them, or you are using binding. In that case, all you need is having the code to update your data model, and then notify the front-end code to reflect the changes.

Comment: The data is displayed in a list box. The data is dynamically loaded by a data table.

Answer (score 0):

The loop and code to set/select all items in the listbox can be this:

```
    For Each li As ListItem In ListBox1.Items
        li.Selected = True
    Next
```

Quite sure even in very old versions of asp.net, the listbox has most settings - including the ListBox1.SelectedIndex

but, regardless the selected property should work. Do remember to set the listbox to allow multiple selections in the property sheet.

Comment: I work in c # .net and not vb. I used this similar code:

                            For Each (ListItem item in ListBox1.Items.Rows)
                           {
                                item.Selected = True;
                           }

I used Rows instead of just .Items because (with items) it threw me this error in Visual Studio: "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'system.data.datatable' because 'system.data.datatable' does not contain a definition for 'getenumerator', or it is inaccessible "

Comment: Now I compiled well in VS( using .Rows) but when I verify the application on the web it threw me an exception error: Specified Cast is not valid. at .....

Comment: not aware that the syntax changes from vb to c# (the methods and properties will not change). My example works in a asp.net + webforms. Using c# or vb.net - the properties of the listbox control should not change.  "items" should exist unless this is a different control then a listbox. However, it not clear if you using the data binding abilities of the control, or perhaps you have some diffreent setup. You need to provide the markup and the code behind  you used to fill (load up) the listbox to resolve what you are doing here.